# I have three text file and I want to merge (print) them in one file. using awk programme

Tags: awk

I have three text file and I want to merge (print) them in one file. using awk programme. I used the following code to print or call two different text file, and it is work perfectly. but if I have three or four text file it does not work. any idea, help

```
BEGIN { #1 text file
} # This line is closing the BEGIN
{
if (FNR != NR)
print $0
}
END {
print ""
} # Closing END
BEGIN { # 2 text file
} # This line is closing the BEGIN
{
if (FNR == NR)
print $0
}
END {
```

Comment: Your question can be answered as simple as `awk '{print $0}' file1 file2 file3 file4`. I suppose that you need something else.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `awk` for this, `cat` is the right tool

```
$ cat file1 file2 file3 > mergedfile
```

but, of course `awk` will do as well

```
$ awk 1 file1 file2 file3 > mergedfile
```